How to make date field on sharepoint non editable when its customized on power app?
I have customized form on power app and its using datasource(sharepoint), when the link item is shared, noticed i cant make datefield non editable from the form. Here is my screen shot below. What code can i write to prevent users not to edit this field from sharepointlibrary document when item is shared as link from power automate?
enter image description here

You have to set the DisplayMode property of your date picker control in Power Apps as per your requirements.
Set it to below to make it non-editable and show value as text value:
DisplayMode.View

Set it to below to make it non-editable and show value as disabled text:
DisplayMode.Disabled

Documentations:

Date Picker control in Power Apps
Core properties in Power Apps - DisplayMode


OR you can try making the changes at data card level as mentioned here: How to Mark Power Apps Form Fields as Read Only:

